# n-dimensional array to n-nested list

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have an object that can be an Object[] of n-dimensions and I need to convert this to an n-nested list with the same representation, ie [][][] becomes ArrayList>>. I know the size of n at runtime via a variable. Another caveat is that objects in the 'lowest' array must be processed before adding to the 'lowest' list; the objects cannot just be copied across. Here is the simple case of a 1 dimensional array

```
Object array; // argument

List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
for(Object o : (Object[])array) {
     list.add(process(o));
}
```

This example does not take into account the dimensions and so 'just works' for the simple case but fails in the complex one. How can I handle the n-case in a generic manner?

Comment: Ah, and what is your exact question?

Comment: How to actually do the case with a multidimensional array, edited the OP

Comment: I guess your array is not defined dynamically, so why can't you use a unique method to perform this?

Comment: HINT : Use recursion to achieve this.

Comment: I know what general approach is needed however I have a lymph node infection and can't think properly, ideally I'm just looking for a nice worked example today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object process(Object possibleArray) {
    if (possibleArray instanceof Object[]) { // is array
        Object[] array = (Object[]) possibleArray;
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(array.length);
        for(Object o : array) {
             list.add(process(o));
        }
        return list;
    } else {
        return possibleArray;
    }
}
```